# error after push and pull from git

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

i had a android studio project and it was wroks. I had push it to gitlab and after remove it , i had pull it again. 
now i get this error when i want to build my gradle:

```
Error:The module 'app' is an Android project without build variants, and cannot be built.Please fix the module's configuration in the build.gradle file and sync the project again.
```

it's my build.gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sample.spart.com"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

what is the problem and how i can fix it??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try invalidating your cash.
in Android Studio:
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Sharing your project's build.gradle file may help.